# Php textual representation of numeric month

Tags: php

I need a quick opinion on this I am building a CMS and I am using Php and Mysql,now doing the update part of the page but the problem is now I can collect the date from my MySql database and split it into different fields so that they go into the default selection in my select date tab but when it comes to month,what i get is the numerical day such as 02.But i want to convert it to the textual representation.pls how can I  achieve this.Thanks
below is my code;

```
<?php $mydate = $sel_job['deadline'];list($year ,$month,$day)=explode("-",$mydate);?>
     <label for="deadline">Deadline</label>
     <em>*</em><select name= month>
            <option selected value="<?php echo $month;?>">
            <option value=2> February
            <option value=3>March
            <option value=4>April
            <option value=5>May
            <option value=6>June
            <option value=7>July
            <option value=8>August
            <option value=9>September
            <option value=10>October
            <option value=11>November
            <option value=12>December 
      </select>
```

Comment: close your option tag:

`<option>month</option>`

wrap your value in ":

`<option value="12">December</option>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a function that has a switch statement that returns each month name for a passed in numeric month.  There's probably one out there on the Interwebs somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourdatefield, '%Y-%b-%d') ...
```

will return the date in '2011-Jul-14' format.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you define an array of month names and then just reference into the array with your numeric month?

```
<?php
$month_names = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "September", "October", "November", "December");
?>
...
<?php echo $month_names[$month - 1]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$textmonth = date('F', strtotime('2000-' . $numbermonth . '-01'));